# dompdf 0.8.2 generates PHP errors: "Uncaught Error: Class 'Dompdf' not found"

Tags: php, dompdf

The legacy application I'm working on uses `dompdf` to generate PDFs from html content.  We are working to updating php 5x to php 7x, so we needed to update `dompdf` from **0.6.1** to **0.8.2**.

I first tested 0.8.2 in a standalone file, and it works fine.

In the application, pdf creation occurs within a function, like this *(but more complicated IRL)*:

```
function createPDF($html,$filename,$paper,$orientation)
{
    require_once("static/dompdf_0.8.2/autoload.inc.php");
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename);
    return true;
}
```

This generated `PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)` against the `use Dompdf\Dompdf` line in the function above.

I tried moving the require and use lines outside of the function *(again simplified)*

```
require_once("static/dompdf_0.8.2/autoload.inc.php");
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

function createPDF($html,$filename,$paper,$orientation)
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename);
    return true;
}
```

This now generates `PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Dompdf' not found` on the `$dompdf = new Dompdf();` line.

Is there a relatively painless way to get dompdf 0.8.2 working within a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work:

```
require_once 'static/dompdf_0.8.2/src/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

function createPDF($html,$filename,$paper,$orientation)
{
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename);
    return true;
}
```

Make sure the `require_once` is executed (successfully) to load the `autoload.inc.php`.

Comment: Selected yours as correct, however I discovered that I just needed to have the `require` and `use` lines in the same file as the function.   When I moved those two lines to a config file, I continued getting the same error.    Unsure why, but I have a workaround now.

Comment: @acoder Because `use Dompdf\Dompdf` means you're importing said namespace and then the active file knows that `Dompdf` actually means `\Dompdf\Dompdf`. You could skip the `use` statement if you really want by doing `new \Dompdf\Dompdf();` instead.